# Install and use autocomplete in jupyter lab 4.1.2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter lab 4.1.2. is there like an extension that can suggest code while I'm typing my code in jupyter lab. I tried installing tabnine and hinterland extension, but it seems like it's disabled. I checked the list of extensions installed using cmd and even though these extensions are listed there, these won't work in the jupyter lab environment.

Comment: the best autocompletion that i have seen is in `vs code`. so switch to this editor if it is a priority. You can run a jupyter notebook in vs code.

Comment: I'm using jupyter lab as its very comfortable in viewing dataframes

Comment: Autocomplete should be working without you needing to do anything in JupyterLab 4.1. It is built in now. How did you install the latest JupyterLab? To rule out something about your browser interfering, go [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/f3f7aed7c87bb15e07009bb29a601ed8) and click 'launch binder' and try things in that session. For example, in a new notebook, type `pr` and then hit tab and it should suggest `print` and some other below. If you enter `pri` in a new cell and hit tab twice it will complete it to `print`.

Comment: i installed by using the pip command in cmd

Comment: I'm looking for autocomplete feature that give suggestions to the code like say when I type out a function it gives me the parameters required for the function